# JAXB: a parent contain a list of a same child, how to obtain this list

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a XML format that I want to marshal using JAXB and it looks a bit odd to me. Here is the XML

```
<root>
    <parent>
         <child>1</child>
         <child>2</child>
         <child>10</child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

I want to get the List of child back. Usually if the `parent` has multiples different `child`, I would make `parent` a class, and use `@XmlElement` to refer to `parent` from `root`, but in this case `parent` only have 1 `child`, and it repeat multiple times, so it is a bit odd to me. **The XML format can be changed**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following leveraging `@XmlElementWrapper`:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="parent")
    @XmlElement(name="child")
    private List<String> children;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Comment: Yup, this is exactly what I need. Reading your blog now. Thank you.

Comment: let forget about collections for a minute. You know how MOxy JAXB implementation can allow people to map out the XML path using `@XPath` or `@XmlPath` (I think, not sure the different), does this implementation have something similar MOxy implementation or whenever there is a parent and child relationship and it is not a collection, we have to use `class` to represent them?

Comment: @HarryPham - `@XmlPath` is an extension offered by the MOXy JAXB implementation (I'm the MOXy lead).  Standard JAXB APIs offer wrapper elements for collections.  If you wanted this behaviour for unary properties you could leverage an `XmlAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered adding `List` in your `Parent` class and annotating it with `@XmlElement`?

```
@XmlElement
protected List<Child> child;
```

Comment: that was my first thought of doing it as well. But since it is a bit silly to create a `Child` class with just 1 variable in it, i was just wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. Then answer suggested above is a much better option.